# My git repository changes are constantly flagged as assume-unchanged

Tags: windows, git

I've been using git on windows for years without any major issue.
However, it's been some time now that I believe I have something that tempers with my local git repositories and from time to time flags my modified files as assume-unchanged to the point I have an alias that runs all my repo files and `update-index --really-refresh --no-assume-unchanged` each and every one of them, and I use it nearly before every `git status`. But this is no way to live! :P

I had removed ConEmu from my machine in hope this might help, but didn't get any results (mind, I should probably restart my machine before). I doubt VS code has anything to do with it. I'm at lost tbh. Is there any git config value that may cause this?

Has anyone experienced a similar issue and found the evil forces that are behind this Machiavellian mechanism? I wish to name and shame it throughout the universe...

Seriously though, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You say you believe your files are flagged with assume-unchanged : did you confirm this belief ?

Comment: Next time you have this feeling : run `git ls-files -v | grep '^[a-z]'` before running your alias. Files flagged as "assume-unchanged" are marked with a lowercase letter when listed with `ls-files -v`.

Comment: Other culprits that could be messing wih your files : file syncing agents, such as the clients for OneDrive, Dropbox, Google drive, ownCloud ... It is definitely not a good idea to place a `.git` folder in a synced directory.

Comment: @LeGEC thanks for the prompt reply- so I ran `git ls-files -v | grep '^[a-z]'` and I get a list of files prefixed by h and a space (`h some/file/path`). As far as I understand there's some sort of (aggresive?) caching that I need to undo. Any further ideas?

Comment: Oh, yeah- and I don't work in a synched directory, good one though- might be useful for someone ;)

Comment: Also, after noticing this behaviour some time ago, I have tried to set the fscache value in my gitconfig file under [core] to false, but to no avail. What I do seem to notice is that **ALL files in my repository are being output by git-files -v prefixed by h and a space**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after messing around with vs code, resharper and sublime text (uninstalling everything, deleting leftovers, restarting the machine and so on)- nothing was coming up as the reason behind this weird behaviour.

And then I commented out all of my gitconfig file- and the behaviour was gone. It then took me no time to figure out the reason behind this behaviour was the following configuration that was set to true:

`core.ignoreStat`

I have no idea how and when did it sneak into my gitconfig file and got set to true, but hopefully this will help others who may experience this.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but on Linux. The answer from OP about git config didn't work for me but got me looking in the right direction.

The git config option `core.fsmonitor` was set to true (carried over from my Windows config where this was an experimental option that improved performance). On my Linux system, this causes basically no file system changes to be detected by git. Now that I've removed it, everything works just fine.

Hope this helps someone else with the same issue.

Comment: That sounds really subtle! Thanks for the info, I'm sure it'll help someone.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment : something (some script or some other process) is setting the `assume-unchanged` flag on each of your files.

You may look into your `.git/hooks` directory (also check `git config core.hooksPath` to see if you have a custom hooks directory configured), or some other script/task that would pass on all the files in your repo.

If you really don't have a clue about what might be causing this : use `grep -e "assume-unchanged" -r .` (to try to spot a script which would run `update-index --assume-unchanged`), first in your repo, then in your home dir, in last resort from `/` ...

Comment: I'm running your grep in an attempt to find something, will let you know. thx

Comment: well, unfortunately, I couldn't find any trace of a script with "assume-unchanged" in its content. I'm afraid this might be in some executable somewhere, or maybe in some script that was running that grep access was refused. The odd thing is that it's been now happening on 2 different machines. Might be a combo of vs pro & vs code extensions or something like that... :(

Comment: Just checking : when you run `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged some/file` in your terminal, it *does* remove the "assume unchanged" bit, right ? (status letter of `ls-files -v` should be uppercase)

Comment: Otherwise : check your extensions in vs/vscode. The bare IDEs would not do this (I highly doubt it, I didn't click through all the options in "Team / VCS" though).

Comment: once I run git update-index --no-assume-unchanged some/file, that file comes out of ls-files -v as `H some/file`; so I suppose that rules out some problems with git itself? If so, I will have to do a vs/vs code extensions check...